# Sqoop 2 restart with no more job

Tags: derby, sqoop2, sqoop

Today I restarted mysqoop server and now all my jobs and links seems to have gone away.
Sqoop is working with a derby database :

org.apache.sqoop.repository.jdbc.url=jdbc:derby:@BASEDIR@/repository/db;create=true

Do you have any clue on how i can put them back?

Comment: Do you have any more details about the Derby configuration? Specifically, what was the Derby JDBC Connection URL?

Comment: Perhaps the setting of BASEDIR has changed, and your old database was in a different database, while your new database is in the new location of BASEDIR. Have you tried searching your hard disk? Note that since 'create=true' was specified, Derby would have quietly created a new empty db in the new location.

Comment: That's it ! My base was in ~/sqoop_install_dir/@BASEDIR@/repository/. After restart, the server create a new ~/@BASEDIR@/repository. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BryanPendleton could you write an answer so i could close this question?

Comment: thanks for the nudge, good to hear it helped you fix your issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the setting of BASEDIR has changed, and your old database was in a different database, while your new database is in the new location of BASEDIR.

Have you tried searching your hard disk?

Note that since 'create=true' was specified, Derby would have quietly created a new empty db in the new location.